# Azure DevOps Agent Job automatically select Pool: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, devops-services

I have created two Agent Jobs.One is for Linux and another for windows. The first agent job trigged the correct build machine as mentioned in YAML file. But the second agent job is not working as expected. It automatically selects the 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'.

YAML code

```
jobs:
 job: TestA
 timeoutInMinutes: 10
 pool: 'PoolA'

 job: TestB
 dependsOn: TestA
 condition: succeeded('TestA')
 timeoutInMinutes: 10
 pool:
 vmImages: 'windows-latest' 
 Name: 'PoolB'
 demands: 
   Agent.Name -equals 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Can you share your pools?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below script could make you avoid the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There has one incorrect syntax in your YAML script: `Name`. It should be `name` here. Also, `vmImages: 'windows-latest'` target to Hosted agents, if what you are picking here is self-agents pool, you should not configure `vmImages` here.

Below is the correct format:

```
jobs:
- job: TestA
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool: 'pool-name'

- job: TestB
  dependsOn: TestA
  condition: succeeded('TestA')
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool:
   name: 'pool-name'
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals 'agent-name'
```

---

In addition, there's another thing you need know.

When you use `demand` in **YAML**, our system will automatically **attach** an another demand to it: check its `Agent.Version`. This is the old default check we made to YAML script. You should pay attention to it since it would cause your pipeline failed sometimes.

*This cannot be override and ignored until now. But we have a task in our backlog to try to handle this.*